# Нахождение одинаковых изображений с разным расширением

Tags: python

Моя проблема заключается в том что нужно находить одинаковые изображения по содержанию, но разними расширениями. Пример: картинка500х500 и точно такая же 1000х1000. У меня есть функция которая принимает на вход 2 изображения, в результате она возвращает изображения одинаковые/разные. Пробовал через матрицу проверять каждый элемент с каждым. Но на данных 10к+ этот процесс слишком долгий. Вариант был находить условную сигнатуру изображений, и одинаковые сигнатуры проверять через функцию. Но не могу найти хороший способ, что бы сигнатура была одинаковой у изображения с разным расширением. Подскажите способ нахождения сигнатур

Comment: а у Imagemagic вроде есть метод signature.

Comment: попытался установить и как то связать с пайтон не выходит, может есть исходный код, или алгоритм как это работает, попробовал бы реализовать вручную

Comment: есть для python binding api для imagemagick, называется wand. https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.7/

Comment: А как картинки разного размера могут вообще быть одинаковыми попиксельно? Наверное, всё же задача искать *сильно похожие* изображения, а не *одинаковые*? Для одинаковых просто `crc` какая-нибудь считается и если размер и `crc` одинаковые, то картинки одинаковые. А вот с похожестью несколько сложнее, да.

Comment: изображения с одинаковом содержанием, но разным разрешением. да пиксельно они разные. я пробовал переводить изображения в черно-белое и высчитывать соотношения, на тестовой выборке из 7 изображений где 3 одинаковых(2 полностью одинаковый и третье с огромным разрешением) результат был хорошим. но на выборке с 300 изображениями слишком много было совпадений